# Aspect Oriented Programming: What do you use PostSharp for?

Tags: aop, postsharp

I would like to ask users of the AOP framework Postsharp, what specifically are you using the framework for?

Also, I know it's use has a big negative impact on build times, but how about runtime performace?  Is there much of a hit?

Thanks,

S

Comment: Seems to me like this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879863/other-than-logging-and-transaction-management-what-are-some-practical-applicatio

Comment: @Ngu Similar - but I want to ask it from a .net perspective (which postsharp is) - some of the uses in other languages (e.g. for observer in Java) are not relevant for .net

Answer (score 2):

I use it to remove the property name smell from INotifyPropertyChanged methods, and it hasn't hugely affected runtime performance.

Comment: Can you provide an example please ?

Comment: http://www.postsharp.org/blog/introducing-postsharp-20-1-notifypropertychanged gives you an idea of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I use the compile time weaving to add extra functionality to some methods that have been decorated with a certain attribute.

Like [here](http://fgheysels.blogspot.com/2008/08/locking-system-with-aspect-oriented.html).

Answer (score 1):

In short, it makes development faster, code more maintainable and easier to understand. There doesn't have to be a performance hit when you are willing to put in the effort.

Answer (score 0):

We use it to inject our own aspects (persistent property accessors, construction notifiers, session & transaction activators, etc.) in [DataObjects.Net](http://wiki.dataobjects.net).